# ms access for each field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to set all Nulls in a table (tblIdea) to NS but the following code throws an 'Object Required' error and highlights the line starting with 'If.'

```
Sub CommitNS()

Dim db As dao.Database
Dim tdf As dao.TableDef
Dim fld As dao.Field

Set db = CurrentDb
Set tdf = db.TableDefs("tblIdea")

For Each fld In tdf.Fields
  If fld Is Null Then
  fld = "NS"
End If

Next fld

Set tdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss the actual update:

```
Sub CommitNS()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim Update As Boolean

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Select * From tblIdea")

    While Not rst.EOF
        For Each fld In rst.Fields
            If IsNull(fld.Value) Then
                Update = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Update = True Then
            ' Record needs update.
            rst.Edit
                For Each fld In rst.Fields
                    If IsNull(fld.Value) Then
                        fld.Value = "NS"
                    End If
                Next
            rst.Update
            Update = False
        End If
        rst.MoveNext
    Wend
    rst.Close

    Set fld = Nothing
    Set rst = nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```